# Get Count of assets in HyperLedger Composer Query?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to write a query in HyperLedger Composer that returns me the count of assets that I have in hyper ledger.
I have thousands of records. I don't want to fetch them all and calculate count. Data transfer will be slow

I want the query to return the count.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no `count` in the composer query language.

You would have to create a query to select all the assets then check the length of the results.  For example with the Basic Sample Network:

```
query selectAssets {
 description: "Select all assets"
 statement:
   SELECT org.example.basic.SampleAsset
}
```

then execute it:

```
let results = await query('selectAssets');
let count = results.length;
```