# How can I get the total amount of assets use Query function?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

As the tutorial of Query, I can use statement to query assets, participant like sql. But my question is can I query the assets use `Count()` to get the length of a specified assets?If it is not effective, how can I get the total amount  or latest element of the assets?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663196/get-count-of-assets-in-hyperledger-composer-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer query language offers a very limited set of queries. An overview can be found at [Hyperledger Composer Query Language](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/query-language.html).
There you may see that this query language does not support any aggregation functions like count, sum, max, min, ... yet.

The consequence is that you need to execute a query which filters your data properly to avoid huge arrays and then apply the respective aggregation in JavaScript as shown in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663196/get-count-of-assets-in-hyperledger-composer-query) david_k has given.

For the latest element it might be e.g. possible to sort by id and then read the "last" entry of the result.