# How to avoid logging query result in logic.js

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer

In my bna files, I added statement like:

```
const validateActions = await query('selectAllValidateActions');
```

In one transaction implement of `logic.js`. I invoke this transaction, the ledger will log all the query results, e.g `query('selectAllValidateActions')` might get 10000 records, and the ledger will log all the 10000 records, but I just want to get the total amount of asset `ValidateAction`, this cost too much storage capacity.
My question is how can I avoid logging query result in logic.js

Comment: Unfortunately there is no count in the composer query language, the limitation is in the underlying CouchDB support and captured [here](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2809?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true) . FYI this has already been answered here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663196/get-count-of-assets-in-hyperledger-composer-query

Comment: Yeah, I have followed the suggestion to use Query in my  logic.js, but I have thousands records in my bc, and when I Query them, the results would be logged in ledger which cause the ledger logged too many useless records, how can I avoid to log the records and use the query in my logic.js?

Comment: I assume you've tried a read-only, query (non-committing) transaction as shown in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts#read-only-transaction-processor-functions (section on read only transactions) ? Could schedule a job (client that call's a read-only (query) transaction) that counts no. of entries every x (minutes|hours), and store it somewhere (ie in the business network as a listing asset). Then your query can query the count listing asset (little to no cost). I mean, the asset `ValidateAction` is a moving target in any case (a 'point in time' count).

Comment: Thank you, and I will follow your advise

Answer (score 0):

Normally querys in hyperledger fabric is performed by a file named (queries.qry) Name of file should be excetly same. and you can write something like this:

```
query getCupData { 
  description: "see all of the participants that have worked with a particular" 
  statement: 
        SELECT org.ibm.coffee.cupCoffee 
}
```

Where cupCoffee would be Your asset type along with namespace.
This file should be made before creating BNA file.